# program only gets 1 of the things

Tags: c#, console

I learn in school java but I need  to use C# for a project that my friend needs. I converted the things from java that dont work in c# and changed them, but i got a problem that happens when I run the program. this is a part from it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
      Console.WriteLine("put N");
      int bign= Console.Read();
      Console.WriteLine("put n");
      int n = Console.Read();
      Console.WriteLine("put t");
      int t = Console.Read();
}
```

it only gets the N and then nothing happens.
please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Console.Read` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it
>   terminates when you press the Enter key. Pressing Enter appends a
>   platform-dependent line termination sequence to your input (for
>   example, Windows appends a carriage return-linefeed sequence).
>   **Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character at a time. After the final character is retrieved, Read
>   blocks its return again and the cycle repeats.**

As a solution, you can use [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and parse them to `int` with [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
int bign, n, t;
Console.WriteLine("put N");
string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("put n");
string s2 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("put t");
string s3 = Console.ReadLine();
Int32.TryParse(s1, out bign);
Int32.TryParse(s2, out n);
Int32.TryParse(s3, out t);
```

Comment: So how do i put all of them in the debugging window?

Comment: I mean, in the java debbuging, you put a number and press enter. what do i need to press in this case??

Comment: @user3519124 Updated my answer. Take a look.